# XSL doesn´t work under chrome

Tags: xml

I'm trying to create a xsl file for a xml, but in chrome it doesn't work.

I know, that chrome only support v1 from xsl (looking at w3school).

In firefox my code is working. Its only test code at the moment.

xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    hallo welt
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="trans.xsl"?>

<doc>

</doc>
```

I've looked for the same problem on the web, but haven't found anything that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you testing this on a file: URL? In chrome I get this in the console:

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///home/me/Downloads/XML/trans.xsl from frame with URL file:///home/me/Downloads/XML/test.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

That looks like matching domains, protocols, and ports to me... Probably some other security-related feature blocking it. At least now you have an error message to google for.

Moral: when something breaks, use the browser console! :)